# How do we use the right hand rule for Stokes' theorem?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

> Let $C$ be the intersection curve between the plane $z = 10 - x - y$ and the cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 1$, oriented such that the projection of the curve onto the xy-plane is positively oriented. Determine the work done by the force field $\mathbf{F} = (x, x^3, z^3)$ in circulating around the curve $C$.

Long story short I parameterized the curve using polar coordinate:
$$r(t,r) = (r\cos(t), r\sin(t), 10 - r\cos(t) - r\sin(t))$$
Then I partial differentiated with respect to t and r and then took their cross product to get the normal vector:
$$r_{t} \times r_{r} = (-r, -r, -r)$$

The curl of $F$ became $F = (0,0, 3x^2) = (0,0, 3r^2\cos^2(t))$ and the dot product between the normal and $F$ is then $-3r^3\cos^2(t)$.

$$\iint_{D} -3r^3\cos^2(t) = -\frac{3\pi}4$$

The correct answer is positive, and it got me thinking is because it says in the question that curve projection on the xy-plane has a positive orientation and using the right hand rule, the normal points upwards. This means that I've to change the direction of my normal vector right? Is this the only reason?

While we are on the subject, I don't need to use Jacobian determinant right? As in multiply by "r" when I parametrize it. Is it because I am already calculating the change in the area caused by the variable change when I take the cross product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parametrization of the given **curve** $C$ is wrong. In the first place because it has two parameters $r$ and $t$ for a $1$-dimensional object (a curve).

Anyway, a positively oriented (counterclockwise) parametrization of the **curve** $C$ is
$$\mathbf{r}(t) = \left(\cos(t),\sin(t), 10-\cos(t)-\sin(t)\right)\quad \text{for $t\in[0,2\pi]$.}$$

A parametrization of the plane **surface** $S$ such that $\partial S=C$ is
$$\mathbf{r}(x,y)=(x,y,10-x-y) \quad\text{with $(x,y)$ such that $x^2+y^2\leq 1$.}$$
By the right hand rule, the induced orientation on $S$ is upwards and $d\mathbf{S}
=(1,1,1)$ which is opposite to yours.
Hence, applying Stokes' theorem, we find
$$\begin{align}
\int_C \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{s}&=\iint_S \text{curl} \mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}\\
&=\iint_{x^2+y^2\leq 1}(0,0,3x^2)\cdot (1,1,1) dxdy\\
&=\int_{0}^1\int_0^{2\pi}3r^2\cos^2(t)\, rdrdt=\frac{3\pi}{4}.\end{align}$$

Comment: My bad, it was a wrong vector field and a cylinder, this was another question under the one I wanted to solve and while typing I accidentally mixed them up. Sorry for the confusion I've edited it now.'

Comment: I apologize again, see edits. I am a little stressed so I'm seeing things that are not there. This time I promise, everything is correct.  Sorry for wasting your time. Check the Z component also, it is not 10.

Comment: I see your edits now, but is it wrong to parameterize a curve in 3D with 2 variables? But any ways did I use the right hand rule correct (not in my computation) but in my explanation of why I'mm wrong?

Comment: The parametrization of a curve in any dimension has just ONE parameter. If you apply Stokes' theorem you need to parametrize a surface whose boundary is the curve. Any orientable surface has TWO orientations. You are wrong because the orientation of your parametrization of the surface is the opposite of what you need.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. But when I asked if I was correct I was talking about my usage of the right hand rule. Can I verify using "right hand rule" whether my parameterization gives wrong orientation?

Comment: Given a surface parametrization $r$ you have TWO orientations: $r_{t} \times r_{r}$ or the opposite $r_{r} \times r_{t}$. Since the curve is positively oriented, by the right-hand rule,  you need the upward orientation (the one with positive $z$ component). You chose the wrong one (its $z$ component is $-r<0$).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help!